# Why does my footer border show up twice?

Tags: html, css, double, border, footer

For some reason when I preview my webpage in a browser the border I applied to the footer appears as a double line. What am I doing wrong? I'm brand new to html/css so it's probably something super simple. Any help would be appreciated!

Here's my HTML:

```
<div class="footer">
<footer>
    <p class="footer">&copy; 2015 Brian Funderburke</p>
</footer>
```

And here's my CSS:

```
.footer{
border-top:1px solid #000;  
margin: 0;
padding: 0; }

.footer p {
margin: 10px;
padding: 0px;}
```

Comment: because **.footer** class you calling two times.

Comment: Wow so I'm totally retarted. Thanks for helping me guys, I can't believe how obvious that was

Comment: @SHAZ unsung hero my friend!

Answer (score 3):

You have the `.footer` class applied to the `<p>`, so it has a border as well:

```
<div class="footer">
<footer>
    <p>&copy; 2015 Brian Funderburke</p>
</footer>
</div>
```

Refer to this amazing graphical representation to visualize what is going on:
[image: red circles!]
Since you applied the class `.footer` to the `<p>`, as well as it's parent, they both have a border, making the effect of a double border:

```
.footer{
  border-top:1px solid #000;  
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0; 
}
```

you should remove the `footer` class from the `<p>`, and problem solved.

Answer (score 2):

Because you have two .footers classes in use. Remove the div class footer.

```
<footer class="footer">
   ...
</footer>
```

That should be enough.

Comment: Thanks! Problem solved. Can't believe how simple that was.

Comment: I personally would accept Jacob Gray's answer as the solution. He uses a clear explanation that will help future users. :)

Comment: @Chris or hungerstar's answer, it explains it as well. But, I don't think the OP realizes you can accept answers...

Comment: @JacobGray Yeah, That works too. I saw yours first though. ;) hahaha. Too bad, if the OP doesn't know how to accept. This still may help some beginners to CSS and HTML regardless though. So, there is a win in that!? Right?

Comment: @Chris yep, that is what SO is for :D

Comment: @JacobGray I could use the Rep though! lol. I agree though, it is good to just give back, because SO has been a large part of my coding knowledge! :)

Answer (score 2):

It shows up twice because you have two elements with the same class of `.footer`.

Your `.footer` class has the border style and you've applied that class to a `<div>` and a `<p>`.

Either remove `.footer` from one of the elements or do something like the following to simplify selection and markup.

```css
footer {
    border-top:1px solid #000;  
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
footer p {
    margin: 10px;
    padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<footer>
    <p>&copy; 2015 Brian Funderburke</p>
</footer>
```

Answer (score 1):

Because you are using the same class `.footer` twice

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you have `<div class="footer">` after that `<p class="footer">` and you are styling the footer. So you will have a border on both of them so double border. Just change the class on the p - `<p class="copyright">&copy; 2015 Brian Funderburke</p>`